# How to plot two different features while counting them?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph, data-visualization

Suppose I have a DataFrame like this:

```
*Age* *RemoteWork*
18  Sometimes
24  Never
30  Sometimes
15  Never
24  Sometimes
```

and it goes on like that.

How would I plot a graph for example "which shows HOW MANY 24 year olds are in Never group"?

Suppose there are more ages and remote work values. I am basically trying to create a histogram of age which shows remote work value and count.

I am sorry if this is not very clear. If you need anymore info please tell me.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Age'], df['RemoteWork']).plot.bar()`

Comment: This works great too, would have accepted it if you had posted as an answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly your sample data set is limited and does not have additional attributes.  You really need to consider how you want to visualise,  then it's straight forward. Using **matplotlib** two examples.

1. a scatter where have factorized y-axis (not needed just for demonstration)
2. a stacked bar putting ages into age ranges

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""*Age* *RemoteWork*
18  Sometimes
24  Never
30  Sometimes
15  Never
24  Sometimes"""), sep="\s+")


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=[10,5],
                      sharey=False, sharex=False, gridspec_kw={"hspace":0.3})

(df
 .assign(a=lambda dfa: ((dfa["*Age*"]//10)*10).astype(str)+"-"+(((dfa["*Age*"]//10)*10)+9).astype(str))
 .groupby(["a","*RemoteWork*"])
 .agg("count")
 .unstack(0)
 .droplevel([0], axis=1)
 .plot(ax=ax[1],kind="bar", stacked=True)
)
ax[1].set_xlabel("Stacked", weight='bold', fontsize=12)


(df
 .assign(y=lambda dfa: pd.factorize(dfa["*RemoteWork*"])[0])
 .plot(ax=ax[0],kind="scatter", x="*Age*", y="y", c="*Age*", s="*Age*", colormap="jet")
)
ax[0].set_xlabel("Scatter", weight='bold', fontsize=12)
```

[image]